# Oracle 9i to 12c Replication

Tags: oracle, replication, oracle-9i, oracle-forms, fusion-io

I have an old Oracle Forms solution that accesses a 9i database and I have been asked if it's possible to replicate to an Oracle 12c database server, with the intention of using Fusion until a new application is built.

Is it possible to replicate between these two versions? Or is there another way to achieve an active-active replica between the two servers? i.e. log shipping etc.

Comment: I think [Oacle Golden Gate](https://www.oracle.com/middleware/data-integration/goldengate/) is what you need. You need Enterprise Edition and have to license it.

Comment: We currently have Golden Gate setup to move data into a BIDW. The issue would be writing new ETLs to move the data back and forth across the transactional systems.

Comment: Do you need a two-way replication? From my experience it would be safer to use only one master (e.g your old forms dB) and then switch roles after you are sure your new application works as intended. With two active databases and a new application under development there is a chance that unexpected behaviour leads to data corruption.

Comment: I’ve been told we need both running as people need to be slowly trained and migrated to the Fusion system. I’m not sure this will even go ahead now, as it seems to be there too difficult, or just outright impossible. Might just have to work harder on the new app :)

Answer (score 1):

Please consult the [Oracle Update and Migration Guide](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/12.2/upgrd/index.html)

There is no direct upgrade path, for your data a export/import might work. 
Your old Forms application will not work, Oracle 10.1 was the last version that could run old 6i Client/Server Forms,IIRC

Comment: I’m trying to avoid an upgrade, but rather have a side by side system running for the time being.

Comment: Do you think about something in the line of data guard/log shipping? I don’t think this is possible. I haven’t worked with logical standby databases, I think with this different database versions are possible.

Answer (score 0):

if you are using Oracle Data guard, then it will not work since Oracle doesn't support it by default.

using OracleGate middleware might do the trick for you assuming there is no Data guard. and install version is Enterprise. but I advise you to check Oracle support to see if it will work perfectly if you implement it.